# How do I get all cookies from a site, including 3rd party?

Tags: cookies

I've been asked to write a web crawler that lists all cookies (including 3rd party such as Youtube) and then checks them in a database that provides extra info (such as what is the cookie for). Users write their address in a search bar and then receive the info.

The problem is: I'm completly lost! I barely have any idea where to begin from, what to do, and it's starting to give me actual headaches.
I can think up the logic, and I know it shouldn't be a hard problem, but what do I have to use?

I have tried Selenium (still have no idea how it works) with Python mainly, I've looked at Java and even considered C#, but still, the problem is that I don't know where to start this from, what to use to do it. Every step I take is like climbing a wall, only to drop on the other side and find a larger wall.

All I ask is some guidance, no need for actual code.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have to create an abstract layer (with setters and getters) where two kind of data will be stored (1. properties of all cookies like domain, expiry, ... 2. extra info binded to cookies depending its properties). Both those datasources will access the layer with writting. User which is searching some info will access the layer with reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I finally got something going. The trick is Python + Selenium + ChromeDriver. I will post more details in the future once I get this all done.

With Python 3, this is enough to connect to a site and get an output of cookies (they're, in this case, stored in myuserdir/Documents/Default/cookies):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import sys

co = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
co.add_argument("user-data-dir={}".format("C:\\Users\\myuserdir\\Documents"))

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = co) 
driver.get("http://www.example.com)
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
def getCookies(self):
    options = Options()
    options.headless = True
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'./geckodriver')

    driver.get(self.website_url)
    cookie = driver.get_cookies()
    driver.quit()
    return cookie
```

The approach I used is use `get_cookies()` to store cookie file for future use. But sometimes you need to simulate js process to get cookies loaded by javascript code.

Comment: This is not for 3rd party like the question asks.